# Invoking .Net WebService from Java

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I had a .Net webService that returns a custom class, lets call it "MyClass", used like this example:

```
[WebMethod]
public MyClass sampleMethod()
{
    return new MyClass();
}
```

If works ok when invoked from a .Net application.

From a Java application using AXIS I am getting the error "MyClass is referenced but not defined".

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: How are you creating the Java proxy?

Comment: @Richard: I'm creating the Java proxy using eclipse "new webservice client" functionality.

Comment: Then the proxy generation is broken.  I have good experience with the Java 6 web service clients that IntelliJ IDEA creates.

Comment: Why are you using Axis instead of JAX-WS (as part of the standard Java API)?

Comment: I just did the .Net part... Now trying to help someone out.

Comment: Have you tried using Apache CXF?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a Java proxy: This can be achieved by generating a client by pointing axis to the Web Service WSDL location.

Your Web Service might look like this: `http(s)://server:port/path/service_def.asmx` and add `?wsdl` to the end of the wsdl definition (i.e. like this `http(s)://server:port/path/service_def.asmx?wsdl`).

From there, generate and client and use the proxy to talk to your .NET Web Service.

---

**PS** The possible cause for this is that your class is not defined in a namespace. Check your WSDL definition and see if there's an `<xsd:element />` for your class and try adding an `ns:` to it and generate java proxy with Axis.

Comment: Your "MyClass" is declared as `WebMethod`. Can't you declare it as (like in java, since I don't know how to do it in .NET) `WebService` or `XmlRootElement`?

Comment: MyClass is just a class that is returned by the Webmethod named "sampleMethod".

Answer (score 0):

Two things that spring to mind:

1. You're missing a schema that defines `MyClass`
2. A namespace issue surrounding the definition of `MyClass`

People will be able to help you further if you can post the WSDL and Schema(s)