# Web service client programing language

Tags: java, web-services

If I have .asmx (C#) web service is it possible to call from axis java client.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Gogoo. It is possible. When you create a web service client you need to provide the WSDL and for ASMX web services you can provide this by adding ?wsdl at the end of the URL. E.g. http://yourdomain.xyz/services.asmx?wsdl

Axis typically creates the client using the wsdl2java tool.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just on the Axis front, it really would be worth going for Axis2 rather than normal Axis, due to added functionality and stability etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Have a look at this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/222898/Web-Services/java/INVOKE-NET-WEB-SERVICE-JAVA) and  [this (how to Invoking .Net WebService from Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423452/invoking-net-webservice-from-java)